# How to design a very long Scrollview with XCode's Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I usually create views programmatically. This time, I tried to use Storyboard.

The views in Storyboards cannot be longer than the device Screen. How can I set a scrollview with a content size taller than the device screen in my storyboard?

I also tried to use XIB files instead of a storyboard, but then I didn't manage to link the XIB files to the storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the simulated size  ( you can do it in xib also )

1-

[image]

2-

[image]

3-

[image]

**Tip:** if your content is too long you can better think of a `UITableView`

Comment: Thank you! Solved my issue!

Comment: Thanks for the **Tip** +1